# How to stop a thread running through TaskExecutor from the main thread after it doesnt respond in few seconds?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpool

I have used TaskExecutor from spring and futures to get the future from the task,but now when some task doesnt respond in some time I have to stop those tasks.I have tried using Future.cancel() method but its of no use the thread stills seems to be running .Can you suggest me some method to stop it?
My thread is waiting on reading the Html content from a link..so how do i stop the task

Edit: the relevant code:

```
URL link = new URL(Content);
URLConnection yc = link.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer Sbuff = new StringBuffer();
while (((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) &&
        ((Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - TimeatStart) / 1000) < 4) {
    Sbuff.append(inputLine);
}
```

Comment: That depends on what the thread is doing.  We need more information, plus code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't do that. If you want the HTTP request to stop after hanging for a while, then set a timeout on it. It's always best to let the thread finish whatever work it's been given to do.

Edit: Based on your source code, the first thing you need to do is make sure to call connect() on the URLConnection. Otherwise, nothing will happen. Take a look at [Working with URLs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/index.html) in the Java Tutorial. After that, if you still want to set timeouts, use [setConnectTimeout()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) to set the amount of time it should try to connect before timing out and [setReadTimeout()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) to set the amount of time it should wait to receive data after a request is sent.

Comment: I am relatively new to java .How should i time out on HTTP request?

Comment: That depends on how you're making the request. What classes/libraries are you using? Regardless of how it's done, there should always be two timeouts you can set: the connection timeout sets the length of time to wait for a connection to be established, and the socket timeout, which is the length of time to wait for data to come back in response to a request you've made.

Comment: this the code i am using i want the while loop to stop after some time so how should i do that

Comment: URL link = new URL(Content);
   URLConnection yc = link.openConnection();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
   String inputLine;
   StringBuffer Sbuff=new StringBuffer();
   while (((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null )&& ( (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()-TimeatStart)/1000)<4 ) {
    Sbuff.append(inputLine); 
    }

Comment: :the problem is not with reading the data .i get the contents from the Http url ...but in some cases the link just sits it doesnt send any response.In these cases i want to stop the thread...and also i am get contents from different sources (files ,db,http etc) so in all after few seconds i have to stop the execution.so that i can free up the threads to be used by other requests..

Comment: @San: As indicated in my answer, the solution is not to "stop the thread". Use setReadTimeout() to fix the problem of never receiving a response. If you have other requests that are running too long, either request less data or consider sending a HEAD request instead of a GET (which falls under the same heading). Manipulating threads is absolutely not the way to solve this problem.